# Categories not set upon product import

Tags: product, import, category, ce-1.9.0.1

I'm having trouble setting the product categories using System > Import\Export > Import via a CSV file (see link 1 below). Regardless of the combination of field IDs used with the category_ids field in the file, I'm unable to set *any* categories when the product is imported - what I'd like to do is what you see in link 2 below. The hierarchy is field_id 2, 4, and 11.

What am I doing wrong?

[Master product layout](http://cl.ly/0v1y3C2w2y1W)

[Desired category hierarchy](http://cl.ly/image/023X2c0n2M1h)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add product from frontend and assign categories. After creating product go to

> System->Import/Export->Export

.
Export csv file. check all the fields. fill the data in same format. Also one more thing when you are using category names then use same name as in admin(`case-senstive`) Or use same structure for id and then import file. Refresh you `indexing and cache`. the product will be saved.

Comment: Turns out there was nothing wrong with my CSV file (with the exception of calling store "base" instead of "admin"), but the issue was using the System > Import/Export > Import functionality instead of the Dataflows - Profiles option. Once I used this, the categories were set!